# D3 adds path for geojson but not topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a map using D3. I have the same map as a geoJSON file and a topoJSON file. When I load in the geoJSON file, it renders on the page and the `<path>` tag gets filled with `d=...`. But when I change the url to get the topoJSON file, the `<path>` tag remains empty, even though I'm leaving the rest of the code untouched. The svg still renders with the topoJSON request, but nothing appears in it. Any thoughts on what might be going on?

My code:

```
var width = 550;
var height = 570;

var arizonaProjection = d3.geoMercator()
  .center([-111.6602, 34.2744])
  .scale(4500)
  .translate([width/2, height/2]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(arizonaProjection);

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width);

d3.json("geojson/Arizona.geojson", function(error, Arizona) {
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", path(Arizona));
  console.log(path);
});
```

The file `geojson/Arizona.geojson` is stored in a different directory of my local server, as is the topojson file at `topojson/Arizona.json`.

Sample of the topoJSON:

```
"transform":{
  "scale":[0.00003998538143372804,0.000031941344085415994],
  "translate":[-114.81659,31.33218]
},
"objects":{
  "Arizona_88_to_89":{
    "type":"GeometryCollection",
    "geometries":[
      {
      "arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5]],
      "type":"Polygon",
      "properties":{
        "startcong":"88",
        "district":"1",
        "statename":"Arizona",
        "member":{
          "88":{"7845":{"party":"Republican","name":"Rhodes, John Jacob","district":"1"}},
      "89":{"7845":{"party":"Republican","name":"Rhodes, John Jacob","district":"1"}}
    },
    "endcong":"89",
    "id":"004088089001"
  }
    },{
      "arcs":[[6,-5,7,-3,8,-1,9,10,11,12]],
      "type":"Polygon",
      "properties":{
        "startcong":"88",
        "district":"2",
        "statename":"Arizona",
        "member":{
          "88":{"10566":{"party":"Democrat","name":"Udall, Morris K.","district":"2"}},
          "89":{"10566":{"party":"Democrat","name":"Udall, Morris K.","district":"2"}}
        },
        "endcong":"89",
        "id":"004088089002"
      }
    },{
      "arcs":[[-12,13,-10,-6,-7,14]],
      "type":"Polygon",
      "properties":{
        "startcong":"88",
        "district":"3",
        "statename":"Arizona",
        "member":{
          "88":{"10623":{"party":"Democrat","name":"Senner, Georg F., Jr.","district":"3"}},
          "89":{"10623":{"party":"Democrat","name":"Senner, Georg F., Jr.","district":"3"}}
        },
        "endcong":"89",
        "id":"004088089003"
      }
    }
    ]

}
```

Sample of the geoJSON:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-112.75515, 33.99991], [-112.75073, 33.99984], [-112.75034, 33.99992], [-112.74655, 33.99991], [-112.74509, 33.9999], [-112.7442, 33.9999], [-112.74395, 33.9999], [-112.74346, 33.99977], [-112.74331, 33.99973], [-112.74262, 33.99955],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A d3 geopath takes a geojson object, not a topology/topojson object. To use topojson with a d3 geoPath, you must first convert it back to geojson. You can do this quite easily with [topojson.js](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md):

```
var featureCollection = topojson.feature(Arizona, Arizona.objects.counties)
```

Of course you can get the features as an array with:

```
var features = topojson.feature(Arizona, Arizona.objects.counties).features
```

The above assumes that `topology.objects` contains a property for counties, you'll have to take a look at your topojson to find out if counties is correct or not (I'm guessing you might be showing counties). If you used a tool such as mapshaper.org, the property name may be the same as the original file name.

Comment: This was helpful thank you! I've seen a lot of use of .data(topojson.feature...) which I hadn't understood, but I get now that the item after .objects needs to be file specific for the subfield that comes after objects. It looks like for mine it's actually "Arizona_81_to_87" (the original file name). Now it only displays one of the districts but at least it's displaying something!

Comment: I added in `.data(topojson.feature(Arizona, Arizona.objects.Arizona_88_to_89).features)` and now part of the topojson displays, but only part. Any ideas as to why? I can try to share the actual file if that's needed.

Comment: Sharing the file would help if possible.

Comment: I was unsure the best way to share the file (it was too large for js bin) so I have added it above under topoJSON. This is the bottom portion of the file that I am calling with the .object command. The top portion of the file consists of 6 "arcs" of varying lengths - I assume this is the outline of the state itself.

Comment: Can't say really based on the available info, if there are only 6 arcs in the top portion of the file, and the first feature uses arcs 0 through 5 for its outline, there may be some data missing from the file as the other features require the use of more than six arcs.

Comment: I figured it out! I was accidentally conflating `.data` and `.datum`, so even though I had all the data in the file, I was only calling the first part of it. Thank you so much for your help, I now have the whole map rendered on the map.